# I was wondering if there is any way to treat delimiters inside quotes as merely characters and not delimiters

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a massive amount of files that are all made using the same schema. They are put into a format where they are space delimited. A sample file row looks like this:

1 2 abc def "g h" 3

And when I try to use the schema INT, INT, STRING, STRING, STRING, INT, it fails for me because of the space inside the quotation marks.
I know this is where the error is because if I make a sample tab separated instead of space separated, no such error occurs, but that is not feasible for me to do with all of my data. I was wondering if there is any way to be able to indicate in a file upload that delimiters in quotes should not be treated as delimiters but rather as characters? (Rather that all quoted text should be treated as one string.)

I know this feature exists for new line characters, and so I was wondering about delimiters.

Thank you!

Comment: What command are you running, and what is the error? `bq load` should be able to handle quoted strings.

Comment: I was running it through their portal. I get an error that the line has too many elements for the schema

Comment: The specific error is: "Too many values in row starting at position: " and then the row position. And when I run it through bq load, it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The error was there was an extra delimiter character at the end of the file. Now I just need to trim each line of the file before uploading.

Comment: What if you add an extra column, instead of going through every row deleting the last char?

Comment: Because I have way too much data to do that. I'm not concerned with paying for storage, I'm more concerned with speed.

Comment: I don't get what the speed problem would be to having an extra empty column - no storage costs either, as it would be empty.

Comment: I'm saying there's no problem with that. I'm saying there is a problem to go through each file and get rid of the extra character at the end.

Comment: Exactly! So if the problem is going through each file removing each last extra character - why don't you create a schema in BigQuery with one extra empty column, and then you will not have to go through the slow extra char deleting.

Comment: That's what I wound up doing, actually.